# I faced error message Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' when I tried to connect local mysql server

Tags: mysql

I am trying to connect my local MySQL server, but I am facing this error message.

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'
```

I tried many solutions on different websites, but none of them did not work. As an instance, I tried to kill the **mysql** and **mysqld** processes and then restart the **MySQL service**, but not worked.
Or I executed these lines (from another site):

```
sudo chmod -R u+rwx /etc/mysql/
sudo chown -R mysql.mysql /etc/mysql/
```

but did not work and gave me the new error message:

```
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Could you please help me with this problem?
Thanks

Comment: I found the solution on this site:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1008298/cant-start-mysql-server-database-corruption

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after about 3 hours of searching on net, the solution founded on this site :-)
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1008298/cant-start-mysql-server-database-corruption

Edit the my.cnf (`/etc/mysql/my.cnf`) file and add the following lines:

```
[mysqld]
innodb_force_recovery = 1
```

then run the command:

```
sudo systemctl start mysql
```

It may do not work for the first time and you need to increment the number to **`2`** or **`3`**. I will be fixed finally. `:-)`